# Why am I getting following error while I create a new project in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Please see this image to better understand.

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file . (app level)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SDK and other entries into menu File -> Project Structure

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to resolve the `junit` file which is actually the compiler,
To clear that problem try adding the following code to your builds.gradle file

```
 repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
```

And if it works let me know.